# Updating read column when user sees notification

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a notification system, and want to check if the user read their notification. So I added a `read` row. If the value is `0` it's unread, and the other way around for it being read. So in my `foreach` loop, that displays the notification This is how I mark it as read

```
//Mark as read
$mkrd = $con->prepare("UPDATE notifications SET read = 1 WHERE id = :hid;");
$mkrd->bindValue(':hid', $notification['id']);
$mkrd->execute();
```

I believe that the loop will loop, when the user looks at it, and then it'll update to `1`.  Now here's the issue, for some reason it won't update. No PHP errors, or MYSQL errors either. I'm sure I'm doing everything right, any ideas? Also any better way of doing this?

Here's the loop

```
foreach($notifications as $notification) {
     $notification;
     $readntf = 1;
     //Mark as read
     $mkrd = $con->prepare("UPDATE notifications SET read = 1 WHERE id = :hid;");
     $mkrd->bindValue(':hid', $notification['id']);
     $mkrd->execute();
echo $notification['type'];
}
```

Comment: You're gonna need to provide more information to get a useful answer. How are you stepping into this code? How do you know these lines are definitely being executed?

Comment: This looks fine, but we would have to see it in the context of your loop to see how this is executed.

Comment: I use `var_dump` to get the query, I also echo after the statement, and it seems to keep going @esqew

Comment: Just for old times sake, what happens if you remove the `;` from your query.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same issue. `read` doesn't update  @Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the column `read` is a [**Reserved Word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html).

What you want to do is wrap that in back ticks like this:

```
 $mkrd = $con->prepare("UPDATE notifications SET `read` = 1 WHERE id = :hid");
```

---

*Side Note:* You don't really need that closing comma (`;`) in your query :-)